# List indices error in python, tic tac toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing python lessons from this page.
https://inventwithpython.com/chapter10.html
 I have created tic tac toe by typing all the code from above site myself

Sometimes the code works fine. Sometimes I get this error and the game crashes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\tictac.py", line 139, in <module>
    makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)
  File "E:\Python\tictac.py", line 40, in makeMove
    board[move] = letter
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

Here is my code from the game which i typed

```
import random

def drawBoard(board):
    #this functions printts the board
    print('   |   |')
    print('  ' + board[7] + '| ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('  ' + board[4] + '| ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print('  ' + board[1] + '| ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')

def inputPlayerletter():
    #lets the player type the letter which they want to be
    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be X or O?')
        letter = input().upper()

    #first letter is users, second belongs to pc
    if letter == 'X':
        return['X','O']
    else:
        return['O','X']

def whoGoesFirst():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        return 'computer'
    else:
        return 'player'

def playAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again?(yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter

def isWinner(bo, le):
    #returns true if player wins
    #bo is board le is letter
    return((bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or
           (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or
           (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or
           (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or
           (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le))

def getBoardCopy(board):
    dupeBoard = []

    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)
    return dupeBoard

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
    return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
    move = ' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 '.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
        move = input()
    return int(move)

def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, moveList):
    possibleMoves = []
    for i in moveList:
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            possibleMoves.append(i)

        if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
            return random.choice(possibleMoves)
        else:
            return None

def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
    if computerLetter == 'X':
        playerLetter = 'O'
    else:
        playerLetter = 'X'

    for i in range(1,10):
        copy = getBoardCopy(board)
        if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
            makeMove(copy, computerLetter, i)
            if isWinner(copy, computerLetter):
                return i

    move = chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [1,3,7,9])
    if move != None:
        return move

    if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
        return 5

    return chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [ 2,4,6,8])

def isBoardFull(board):
    #return true if the board is filled
    for i in range(1,10):
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print('Welcome to tic tac toe')
while True:
    #reset the Board
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerletter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
    gameIsPlaying = True

    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'player':
            #player's turn
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Hooray! Yoou have won the game!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The gaame is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'
        else:
            #computer turns
            move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
            makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('The Computer has beaten you! You lose. ')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player'
    if not playAgain():
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert:

```
def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, moveList):
    possibleMoves = []
    for i in moveList:
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            possibleMoves.append(i)

        if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
            return random.choice(possibleMoves)
        else:
            return None
```

to

```
def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, moveList):
    possibleMoves = []
    for i in moveList:
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            possibleMoves.append(i)

    if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
        return random.choice(possibleMoves)
    else:
        return None
```

The problem is that because of the indentation you don't calculate all free positions. Instead, you check only the first candidate position if it's free and when it's not you return nothing.